# Counting all prime number in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a function in Haskell that counts all prime numbers, but it doesn't seem to work.
This is how my code looks like:

```
import Data.Char
countPrimeNumbers :: [Int] -> Int
countPrimeNumbers n = all (isDigit) n
```

Anyone has a solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: "a function in Haskell that counts all prime numbers": `countAllPrimeNumbers = 1/0 :: Double`

Comment: Do you mean "...counts all prime numbers up to x" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're wanting is something like

```
countPrimes :: [Int] -> Int
countPrimes ns = length $ filter isPrime ns
```

But you'll have to come up with `isPrime` on your own

---

The `all` function has the type

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

What it does is apply a test to every element in the list, then does a logical AND with all elements.  If you wanted to test if all the elements in a list were prime, you could use it as

```
allPrime :: [Int] -> Bool
allPrime ns = all isPrime ns
```

where

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = undefined -- Test if its a prime here
```

The `filter` function, by contrast, takes the same kind of predicate, but returns only the values that pass the predicate, for example:

```
> :type even
Int -> Bool
> even 1
False
> even 2
True
> filter even [1..10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

So `filter isPrime ns` should return all the numbers in `ns` that are prime, then you just count them with `length`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short Haskell function that enumerates primes from Literate Programs:

```
primes :: [Integer]
primes = sieve [2..]
  where
    sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
```

Apparently, this is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes (thanks, Landei). I think it's still an instructive example that shows you can write very elegant, short code in Haskell and that shows how the choice of the wrong data structure can badly hurt efficiency.

Comment: Compared to an imperative version of countPrimes, this performs really badly when you use this to count primes. Any ideas why?

Comment: @starflyer, the reason the above algorithm performs so poorly is very well explained in [Melissa E. O'Neil's reference article](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).  In short, this is based on an un-optimized Trial Division algorithm and there are much better algorithms.  It should be mentioned that if one intends to sieve for ranges much more than 10 to 100 million, one does not use purely functional incremental sieves as does the author but uses something based on arrays, preferably page segmented.  Also, the author's functional implementation has since been improved.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the list of primes (import Data.List)

```
nubBy (\x y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2..]
```